# Visualize my LinkedIn network

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, social-networks, linkedin

#### The situation

In the past I sometimes used InMaps to see how my LinkedIn contacts were clustered. Unfortunately the service is discontinued, and now I just partially succeeded with Socilab, which is limited to 500 contacts, and thus insufficient..

#### I have searched for solutions, this is what I found

- InMaps: Retired
- MyWebCareer: Site down
- ManyEyes: Retired
- SociLab: Insufficient
- Gephi+python: Complicated

So far the only solution that I have found that may work, is a combination of Python & Gephi [as suggested here](https://linkurio.us/linkedin-inmaps-discontinued-visualize-network-now/).

First of all Gephi failed to run (I have a standard computer with Windows 8) and secondly this would mean that I had to install a whole programming language, to see a picture. Basically this means I might be able to use the solution myself if I invest some time, but it would be hopeless for all my friends who have never ran a script in their life.

#### Hence my question:

How can a simple person currently visualize their LinkedIn network?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin have you found a feasible/workable alternative?

Comment: @GuidoJansen Unfortunately not. Apparently SociLab has acces to information that you can normally not get anymore, so even rebuilding it seems impossible. I logged an issue with the SociLab GIT page, suggesting to store the 500 contacts, and allow you to get the rest tomorrow. So far there is no response.